# REST call not working when component updates via RouteParam

Tags: angular, routes

I have a simple Angular application that uses Route params as an observable so the content in my component updates as my route id changes. I can track the updating route id in my component as needed so the component is updating as needed, but I cannot make a REST call at the same time the content updates and this is where the bulk of my content will eventually come from.

Here is the code in the areas relevant to the issue:

**menu.component.html** uses the element index as an id to pass to content.component.ts

```
<div>
    <h3>Lesson Links</h3>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4" *ngFor="let menu of menus | async; index as id">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <a [routerLink]="['/content',id]">{{menu.lessonName}}</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**content.component.ts** 'grabs' the id from the routerLink in the menu.component.html

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-content',
  templateUrl: './content.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./content.component.css']
})
export class ContentComponent implements OnInit {
id: string;
content;
url = 'api address'
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit(){ 
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
    console.log(params.get('id')); //for logging id (Ill eventually pass the id to the api url)
    this.id = params.get('id');
    this.getContent(); //this isnt getting called each time, but the id from above is logging each time the menu item is clicked.  
  });
  }
  getContent(){
    this.content = this.http.get(this.url); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you put a console in the getContent()?

Comment: The content variable has an async in the template or what? I mean, someone is subscribing to it?

Comment: Exactly.. what is subscribing?

Comment: @satchcoder - the console does log if I add it to getContent() so the function is firing each time a menu item is clicked.

Comment: @MikeOne - Im not having any issues with the observable, its the rest call that will not work. FYI - Im listening to the routeparam so when the id changes, the change is reflected in a another component. Angular will not update a component with the route id changes so it must be tracked manually. Again - all pf that is working - just the rest call isnt, but the function is being called successfully.

Comment: Can you provide the html to see how are you consuming the content variable?

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to the http get method (please find bellow code snippet). Also go through the documentation : https://angular.io/guide/http

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
    console.log(params.get('id')); //for logging id (Ill eventually pass the id to the api url)
    this.id = params.get('id');
    this.getContent().subscribe({
      next: (response) => {
        this.content = response; // you can manipulate the response before assigning it directly to this.content
      }
    });
  });
}
getContent() {
  return this.http.get(this.url);
}
```